# Opposite of Ruby's number_to_human

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Looking to work with a dataset of strings that store money amounts in these formats. For example:

> $217.3M
>
> $1.6B
>
> $34M
>
> €1M
>
> €2.8B

I looked at the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem but it doesn't look like it handles the "M, B, k"'s back to numbers. Looking for a gem that does do that so I can convert exchange rates and compare quantities. I need the opposite of the number_to_human method.

Comment: You may have to write your own. It is pretty quick though. Just matching a few letters and then multiplying.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with something like this:

```
MULTIPLIERS = { 'k' => 10**3, 'm' => 10**6, 'b' => 10**9 }

def human_to_number(human)
  number = human[/(\d+\.?)+/].to_f
  factor = human[/\w$/].try(:downcase)

  number * MULTIPLIERS.fetch(factor, 1)
end

human_to_number('$217.3M')  #=> 217300000.0
human_to_number('$1.6B')    #=> 1600000000.0
human_to_number('$34M')     #=> 34000000.0
human_to_number('€1M')      #=> 1000000.0
human_to_number('€2.8B')    #=> 2800000000.0

human_to_number('1000')     #=> 1000.0
human_to_number('10.88')    #=> 10.88
```

Comment: It's worth noting that "M" can mean "million" (10e6) or "mille" (10e3) and that "billion" can mean either 10e9 or 10e12 depending on the system. Language is confusing and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not be lazy and actually write my own function if anyone else wants this:

```
def text_to_money(text)
  returnarray = []
  if (text.count('k') >= 1 || text.count('K') >= 1)
    multiplier = 1000
  elsif (text.count('M') >= 1 || text.count('m') >= 1)
    multiplier = 1000000
  elsif (text.count('B') >= 1 || text.count('b') >= 1)
    multiplier = 1000000000
  else
    multiplier = 1
  end

  num = text.to_s.gsub(/[$,]/,'').to_f
  total = num * multiplier

  returnarray << [text[0], total]

  return returnarray
end
```

Thanks for the help!